# C# linq ANY boolean negation outer vs predicate

Tags: linq

There is an object that has a property ListA of objects and inside each object a property id(nullable)

There are always two objects in the ListA

Case A

```
if (!mainObj.ListA.Any(object => object.id.HasValue)) 
{
   //do
}
```

vs

Case B

```
if (mainObj.ListA.Any(object => !object.id.HasValue) ) 
{
   //do
}
```

I want to understand why when the id is True/False or False/True the **Case A** does not meet the criteria of statement to enter inside if only enters when the ids is False/False.

Answer (score 0):

You're using **!** before condition in Case A (!mainObj.ListA.Any(object => object.id.HasValue)), which will return true, only when both objects doesn't have value, because of using Any.

For the Case A you need to use the following approach:

```
if (!mainObj.ListA.All(object => object.id.HasValue)) 
{
   //do
}
```

where we changed *Any* to *All* and we go inside this block, when at least 1 of the items doesn't have value.

Comment: Yeah the original thought was that if any elements in the sequence not having a value i want you to enter BUT this doesnt work the way i expected. Inside the any method says  "Determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition."  "Returns:
        //true if any elements in the source sequence pass the test in the specified predicate;" which i think right now is misleading

Comment: But you're checking the opposite thing, which tells if any element Has a value, then return True. And then trying to make opposite of it.

Comment: > any elements in the sequence not having a value i want you to enter.               
                You're checking it only in Case B, however in Case A you're currently checking if all elements doesn't have a value, then enter the block.

Comment: So ANY works only if all the elements satisfy the condition ?

Comment: Any + ! before it, works only if all elements do not satisfy the codition.